# Can't find classpath in Ktor Kotlin application when trying to start exploded application

Tags: java, kotlin, kubernetes, ktor, docker-tilt

I have the following basic bootstrapped Kotlin application that I would like to start in an 'exploded jar state'. I need this to start it this way to use it with Docker Tilt.

```
package com.example

import io.ktor.server.application.*
import com.example.plugins.*
import io.ktor.server.engine.embeddedServer
import io.ktor.server.netty.Netty


fun main(args: Array<String>): Unit =
    io.ktor.server.netty.EngineMain.main(args)

@Suppress("unused") // application.conf references the main function. This annotation prevents the IDE from marking it as unused.
fun Application.module() {
    configureAdministration()
    configureHealthEndpoints()
    configureSockets()
    configureSerialization()
    configureDatabases()
    configureMonitoring()
    configureHTTP()
    configureSecurity()
    configureRouting()
}
```

The specific Tilt block looks as follows:

```
docker_build_with_restart(
  'ktor-java-image',
  './build/jar',
  entrypoint=['java', '-noverify', '-cp', '.:./com/**.*', 'com.example.ApplicationKt'],
  dockerfile='./Dockerfile-tilt',
  live_update=[
    sync('./build/jar/META-INF', '/app/META-INF'),
    sync('./build/jar/application.yaml', '/app/application.yaml'),
    sync('./build/jar/com', '/app/com'),
    sync('./build/jar/logback.xml', '/app/logback.xml'),
    sync('./build/jar/openapi', '/app/openapi'),
  ],
)
```

and the start part of the Dockerfile looks as follows:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine

RUN apk add entr

WORKDIR /app
ADD META-INF /app/
ADD application.yaml /app/
ADD com /app/
ADD logback.xml /app/
ADD openapi /app

ENTRYPOINT java -cp .:./*/com/* com.example.ApplicationKt
```

I get the following error:

```
     ┃ Not Ready       - (ContainersNotReady): containers with unready status: [ktor-java-image]
[event: pod ktor-java-image-c597b9c-rjdtj] Pulling image "localhost:60620/ktor-java-image:tilt-51d991b648ea76bd"
[event: pod ktor-java-image-c597b9c-rjdtj] Successfully pulled image "localhost:60620/ktor-java-image:tilt-51d991b648ea76bd" in 19.922375ms (19.928ms including waiting)
[event: pod ktor-java-image-c597b9c-rjdtj] Container image "localhost:60620/ktor-java-image:tilt-51d991b648ea76bd" already present on machine
k8s_resource(name='ktor-java-image', port_forwards='8080') currently maps localhost:8080 to port 8000 in your container.
A future version of Tilt will change this default and will map localhost:8080 to port 8080 in your container.
To keep your project working, change your Tiltfile to k8s_resource(name='ktor-java-image', port_forwards='8080:8000')
Error: Could not find or load main class com.example.ApplicationKt
[event: pod ktor-java-image-c597b9c-rjdtj] Back-off restarting failed container ktor-java-image in pod ktor-java-image-c597b9c-rjdtj_default(49cf15b8-f5cd-49b0-bb69-200711a36cbc)
Detected container restart. Pod: ktor-java-image-c597b9c-rjdtj. Container: ktor-java-image.
Error: Could not find or load main class com.example.ApplicationKt
```

Just to confirm, the application starts from gradle run without issues:

```
❯ ./gradlew run

> Task :run
2023-12-22 13:11:05.007 [main]  INFO  Application - Autoreload is disabled because the development mode is off.
2023-12-22 13:11:05.245 [main]  DEBUG i.m.c.u.i.l.InternalLoggerFactory - Using SLF4J as the default logging framework
2023-12-22 13:11:05.247 [main]  INFO  i.m.c.i.push.PushMeterRegistry - publishing metrics for LoggingMeterRegistry every 1m
2023-12-22 13:11:05.482 [main]  INFO  Application - Application started in 0.491 seconds.
2023-12-22 13:11:05.482 [main]  INFO  Application - Application started: io.ktor.server.application.Application@526b2f3e
2023-12-22 13:11:05.544 [DefaultDispatcher-worker-1]  INFO  Application - Responding at http://0.0.0.0:8080
<==========---> 80% EXECUTING [9s]
```

Anyone have an idea